# Spring and Neo4j database: Can't authenticate user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Spring application with Neo4j. Spring application normally connected to neo4j database. I did everything according to official documentation. But user is unauthenticated and I don't know why. Can you help me to authentificate user please?

For checking authentification I use endpoint: actuator/health.
Response:

```
{
    "status": "UP"
}
```

According to documentation authentificated user should see sometning like that:

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
    "neo4j": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "server": "Neo4j/4.0.0@localhost(127.0.0.1):7687",
        "database": "neo4j"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter:4.1.1.0'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

My application.properties

```
org.neo4j.driver.uri=bolt://localhost:7687/mydatabase
org.neo4j.driver.authentication.username=neo4j
org.neo4j.driver.authentication.password=123123
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

In my case I had to add additional properties to application.properties:

```
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
management.health.db.enabled=false
```